# Using class objects in functions

Tags: c++, object

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to make a program to do conversions between two objects. I have `Class1`, `Class2` and `Convert`. I want a function that takes in a Class1 object, converts it to a Class2 object and returns the Class2 object. Right now my convert class is basically:

Convert.h

```
#ifndef Convert_H
#define Convert_H
#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"

class Convert
{
public:
    Convert();
    Class1 c1;
    Class2 c2;
    Class2 C1ToC2(Class1);

};
#endif // Convert_H
```

Convert.cpp

```
#include "Convert.h""
#include "Class1.h" 
#include "Class2.h"

Convert::Convert()

Class2 Convert::C1ToC2(Class1 c1)
{
    //conversions

    return c2;
}
```

I have a few questions about this. I don't want to have the convert functions in the other classes which is why I created a separate class.

1. Is this a good way to use functions that I don't want to be apart of the other classes
2. When I compile this class it fails saying "expected initializer before Class2 but since I want to return a Class2 object isn't that how I have to define the function?

Once again I am new to C++, I do have a few books that I'm trying to learn from but they don't really tell how to use objects like this so I apologize if this is a stupid question and I'm doing it completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you can simply use a function directly, you don't need a class `Convert`.

In `Convert.h`:

```
#ifndef Convert_H
#define Convert_H

#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"

// declare the function
Class2 convert( const Class1& input );

#endif
```

and in `Convert.cpp`:

```
#include "Convert.h"

// define the function
Class2 convert( const Class1& input )
{
    Class2 result;
    // do conversion
    return result;
}
```

Note that this is just the basics, it can be improved in several aspects but it should help you to get started and experiment on your own.

Comment: Where would I define this function? Do I just create a blank file?

Comment: @rsay3 I edited the answer to show how your files should look like, I think that's easier than explaining in a comment.

Comment: Thank you! One last question, with the variables do I still include those in the header or can I just initiate them in the .cpp functions?

Comment: @rsay3 Which variables? You need *just* the above, what I have shown is complete.

Comment: Well I'm going to have multiple functions such as `Class2` convert to `Class1` and I will have variables common amongst both of them, should I just define them in each function or can they be global variables?

Comment: @rsay3 It's hard to tell, since you seem to be doing some things that an experienced developer can't even imagine. No offense intended, that's a normal thing. It's just that from your description I still have no idea what exactly you are doing and *how* you are doing that. Maybe create another example (preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) and ask another question?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your second question, the reason the code doesn't compile is because you forgot the curly braces after `Convert::Convert()`. (Or maybe a semicolon. But I assume you wanted to define the ctor)

Comment: `Convert::Convert();` wouldn't be legal either.  A declaration of a member outside the class must actually define it.